# How to simplify the expression "data && data.pwd && data.pwd.length"?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this question has been asked several times and in much clearer terms, but I just don't know the technical term for what I'm looking for. I'm trying to write a conditional statement in the following way:

`if (data && data.password && data.password.length > 7) {// Do something}`

But I know there is a simpler way to write this. Something like

`if (data?password?length > 7) {// Do something}`

What would be the correct formulation? What is the technical term for this type of expressions?

Comment: Yes. It's `data?.password?.length`

Comment: Close. [`if (data?.password?.length > 7) {...}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Optional Chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 3):

Concept you are looking for is called [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

You can modify to : `data?.password?.length`